# Vue Router is duplicating entries in window.history in Safari

Tags: vue.js, safari, vue-router, vue2-google-maps

My `App.vue` has the following setup:

```
// App.vue

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

And `Home.vue` has link to `Gmap.vue`:

```
// Home.vue

<template>
  <div>
    <router-link to="/gmap">vue2-google-maps</router-link>
  </div>
</template>
```

And `Gmap.vue` has `<GmapMap>` component from [vue2-google-maps](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps):

```
// Gmap.vue

<template>
  <div>
    <GmapMap :center="{lat: 0, lng: 0}" :zoom="10">
    </GmapMap>
  </div>
</template>
```

Finally `router.js` is like this:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: "/gmap",
      name: "gmap",
      component: Gmap
    }
  ]
})
```

In Safari, at path `/`, when click `<router-link>`, Safari navigates to `/gmap` and puts `/gmap` path into Safari's `window.history`. So clicking Safari's back button will make Safari navigate back to `/`.

Then clicking `<router-link>` again will make Safari navigate to `/gmap`. However, at this time Safari will put `/gmap` path into Safari's `window.history` twice (first `/gmap` and second `/gmap`). So clicking Safari's back button won't make Safari navigate to `/`. Instead, Safari will navigate to the first `/gmap`.

I confirmed that:

- when Safari went back and forward between first `/gmap` and second `/gmap`, `popstate` event wasn't triggered, and Vue Router didn't catch the changes so none of Navigation Guards were invoked.
- this happens in Safari (macOS 10.13.6 and iOS 11.4.1)
- this doesn't happen if routing to components that don't contain `<GmapMap>` component
- this doesn't happen when routing without Vue Router
- this doesn't happen in Chrome 67 (macOS 10.13.6 and iOS 11.4.1)

**Why does Safari put same path twice?**

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Comment: @sortofimport - were you able to solve this?

Comment: @zerohedge I have posted answer. Please let me know if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Though not an exact answer, to solve the issue wrap `<keep-alive>` around `<router-view>` in `App.vue`:

```
// App.vue

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- Note that <router-view> is wrapped by <keep-alive> -->
    <keep-alive>
      <router-view />
    </keep-alive>
  </div>
</template>
```

Source: GitHub [discussion](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/issues/485#issuecomment-452559569).